# Backbone event aggregator dont trigger events at first view initialization

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm trying to trigger some events at initialize in my views. They work if I back and forth in the browser or if I load a second view, but not at first loading, i.e. when the user lands in the view.

My setup is as follows:

I create an event aggregator at router.js like:

```
socketEvents: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)
```

Then I pass the aggregator to each view like:

```
index: function() {
      this.changeView(new IndexView({socketEvents:this.socketEvents}));
},
```

Then in index.js I do something like so:

```
initialize: function(options) {
  this.socketEvents = options.socketEvents;
  this.socketEvents.trigger('one:event');
},
```

As I said, if I refresh the page doesnt work, if I move to another view and hit back in the browser, the event is triggered.

Why is this happenning? How can I solve this?

Thanks

Editing after first comment:

There are not errors I can/know how to track. At initialize() Either it just does seamlessly the whole transaction: trigger and listenTo, or it completely ignores it at initialize().  Order of execution is as follows: 
 I boot the application with require, from there it loads a class with the router and socket.io client. Then it iniatilizes the socket.io client and uses the router event aggregator. Then it checks if the user is logged, if it is, it triggers an router.event saying the user is logged in. At the socket.io client, there is an event.Dispatcher binding the logged in to initiating the socket. Finally the user is redirector to a index view. Then it happens as I described above.

Comment: There are not errors I can/know how to track. At initialize() Either it just does seamlessly the whole transaction: trigger and listenTo, or it completely ignores it at initialize().

Comment: Yes, initialize is called, and this.listenTo(this.socketEvents,"one:event",this.doThis()); is listening

Comment: yes,sorry my mistake, I mean "this.doThis".